# How do I create a slicer that only affects one column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table with multiple columns, I would like to add a "Previous Date Slicer" so that there is a column that will fetch data from previous dates that the user selects, but it applies this slicer to the entire table so I can't actually create a comparative column and the entire table is filled with data from the dates I have selected.

The intent is that the Previous Data Column will display the information from the previous dates I selected in the slicer column, creating a comparison. One column will have the current dates data, and the other column will have the previous dates data from dates the user specified.

Comment: Use calculate in the measures!!!

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example? I create a measure and apply calculate, and then I create a slicer from that measure?

Comment: For each measure use calculate and use remove filters for remove the filtering shall we have a chat?